# Installed and compiled AOSP and Android Studio.How do I get it to start the AOSP emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

So I have installed Android Studio and its emulator and I have also compiled the AOSP which I downloaded using information from source.google.com.

However now when I type commands:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch
```

then select option 6 which is the x86_64 build and used to run on my Ubuntu

```
emulator
```

the Android Studio emulator starts. How do I get it to start the AOSP emulator?

Comment: This is AOSP emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run emulator command the AOSP emulator is started and not the Android Studio Emulator